# Correct position of brake quick release on Ultegra 6800

Tags: road-bike, brakes, shimano, quick-release

I'd like to know wether the brake quick release lever on the Ultegra 6800 can be kept in any intermediate position between completely closed and completely opened when riding.

Comment: I doubt it. Doesn’t it tend to move in one of both positions when braking hard? Use a cable length adjustment screw.

Comment: No it doesn't move at all when braking hard. Besides when moving the release level it's not smooth but it kind of "snaps", like a watch's movable outer dial.

Comment: Your quick release should be closed. It sounds like you need to adjust your brakes.

Comment: Closed all the way! It WILL open when you brake hard!

Comment: Just because it hasn't opened under hard braking yet, doesn't infer that it never will.  Is there  a  reason you prefer to ride with it  half way?

Answer (score 4):

It should be fully closed. The lever is only intended to be opened to allow the tire to pass during a wheel change or if you hit a pothole and knock your wheel badly out of true. If your pads are too close to the rim you make an adjustment with the barrel adjuster. Riding with the quick release open compromises the braking power of the caliper. You may not notice while riding along normally but in an emergency stop at speed it absolutely will result in slower braking.

Comment: I will add that it could potentially slip under high braking force if not in the fully closed position.